# Styling buttons on CiviCRM public forms

Tags: drupal, button, 5.0

I'm looking to improve the look of buttons on CiviCRM public forms.
I am using a bootstrap sub-theme.
Are the button classes documented anywhere?
Any suggestions for addressing this?

Using Drupal 7 & CiviCRM 5.x

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drupal + CiviCRM you should check out the "[Shoreditch](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch)" theme for CiviCRM which changes the CiviCRM UI to use bootstrap based styling.

[image: CiviCRM Name and Address profile on D7, Civi 5.1.2 using ShoreDitch]

**Note:** *Shoreditch is in Alpha state and undergoing active development, we are using this in production and aside from a few minor issues it's working very well.*

If you're not using Drupal you would want to look at overriding the CSS in your CMS/site theme. You can get the button classes etc using the "Web Inspector" in any major web browser - these are not directly documented at present.

Comment: Shoreditch doesn't address public forms, or at least I haven't seen how.

Comment: @Yossi Shoreditch absolutely covers CiviCRM profiles (public forms), I've added a screenshot to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thanks... Maybe the civicrm_theme module is causing a conflict on my end... does it address mobile displays?

Comment: @Yossi yes - mostly. You'll want to make sure your CRM theme is also bootstrap based or otherwise that it gets out of the way and lets Civi do the heavy lifting. If you find issues with it definitely get them raised as Shoreditch is looking likely to be the future of the CiviCRM UI

Comment: There is also the Civi Bartik Public theme: https://github.com/CiviCooP/civi_bartik_public which is for public civicrm pages. And let you define the color scheme etc...